# What's the point of giving threads names in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, python-multithreading

There doesn't appear to be any way to get a thread by using its name so what exactly is the name argument for when you're creating a Thread? I wanted to use it to identify and recover the thread later on but it doesn't seem that's possible. I'm talking about this Thread module

http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread

Comment: On the page you linked to:  `A string used for identification purposes only. It has no semantics. Multiple threads may be given the same name. The initial name is set by the constructor.`

Comment: I guess that part confused me a little. So it's literally just to identify a process object? As in, if you have a process and want to know "what" it is? It's odd you can't recover a process using the name, but I guess that's a limitation from allowing you to repeat names...

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the name of the thread in the case of an exception being raised in a thread, that way at least I know which thread raised the exception.

Comment: Same is true for all other languages, not only Python.